# AWS Flask session not persistent from PHP requests

Tags: php, session, flask, aws-lambda

I deployed a Flask application to AWS lambda

```
@bp_google_routes.route('/is_authorized', methods=('POST', ))
def google_is_authorized():
    data = json.loads(request.data)

    flask.session['user_email'] = data['email']
    authorized = aws_handler.already_authorized(data['email'])
    return jsonify({'authorized': authorized})


@bp_google_routes.route('/authorize', methods=('GET', ))
def google_authorize():
    if 'user_email' not in flask.session:
        abort(404)

    return 'All good'
```

I'm accessing the application via an PHP backend to first check the authorization `is_authorized` which is a `POST` request and will store the `email` in the session.

Then right after I'll perform a second call to `authorize` which always aborts since apparently there's no email in the session. But there should be from the first request:

```
<?php
    $data = array("email" => "test@test.com");                                                                  
    $data_string = json_encode($data); 
    $aws_endpoint = "https://.../is_authorized";
    $aws_endpoint_auth = "https://.../authorize";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $aws_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json')
    );

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    if ($err) {
        echo "There was an error accessing the requested information!";
    } else {
        $result = json_decode($response);
        if (!$result->authorized) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $aws_endpoint_auth);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            echo $result;
            print_r('False');
        } else {
            print_r('True');
        }
    }
?>
```

Why is the the session not persistent between the two calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `curl` to persist the cookies using a `cookiejar`.

Add the line below to the top of your file:

```php
$cookieFileName = tempnam('/tmp','cookies.txt');
```

Then add the `curl_setopt` calls below to each of your calls:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFileName); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFileName);
```

This way, curl will store & re-use the cookies between requests.